# How to use HAC for Time Series Dataframes with Covariance

Tags: statistics, time-series, covariance

I have a question concerning time series.
I have a Dataframe with several Columns, each containing a time series.
I need a Covariance Matrix of the different columns.
However, my columns are autocorrelated and thus (as far as I understand) the normal covariance won't work.
Is there any way to calculate the HAC variance of the columns and build a covariance matrix based on that?
If not, is there any other way to get such a covariance matrix?

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  I'm a little confused by what you mean by `my columns are autocorrelated`?  Surely all signals are autocorrelated with themselves? You should probably spell out what you're meaning by [HAC](http://www.people.ku.edu/~z397c158/ECON817/HC-HAC.pdf) (heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation consistent, I believe). Perhaps also describe the reason you think this is a problem for your data set.